# Extends Model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Well, I'm newbie in CodeIgniter Framework and i'm trying building a generic Model Class. See:

```
class Basic_Model extends CI_MODEL {

    function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

I want to extends all Models based on Basic_Model, like this:

```
class Pagina_Model extends Basic_Model {

    function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

The problem is when i try to call "pagina_model" from a Controller a got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Basic_Model' not found in /var/www/myproject/application/models/pagina_model.php on line 12
```

If i use "basic_model" in controller everything works fine.

**EDIT 1:**

I created a file named MY_Basic_Model.php in "/application/core" and changed the class name to "MY_Basic_Model". But i got the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MY_Basic_Model' not found in /var/www/myproject/application/models/pagina_model.php on line 12
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this you have to create **Core System Classes** (this is also known as **Method Overriding**).

Create a file **`MY_Model.php`** in **`application/core/`** directory which will **extend** the base **`CI_Model`** class:

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Now you can extend this in your models **(../applicaton/models/)**:

```
<?php
class Pagina_Model extends MY_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**Few things to note here:**
1) The class declaration must extend the parent class.
2) Your new class name and filename must be prefixed with **MY_** (this item is configurable).

**How to configure:**
To set your own sub-class prefix, open your application/config/config.php file and look for this item:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

**Documentation:**
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Comment: I need put "MY" prefix ?

Comment: Yes, the class name must have a `MY_` prefix. Added a note in answer.

Comment: I tried it, look the error: Fatal error: Class 'MY_Basic_Model' not found in /var/www/.../pagina_model.php on line 12

Comment: It must be in `application/core/` directory.

Comment: Yeah, i putted there a file named "MY_Basic_Model.php" but didn't work.

Comment: Weird, try `MY_Model.php` and class name `MY_Model`.

Comment: Can you check this in `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: Also recheck this line `class MY_Model extends CI_Model {`. It should be this (case-sensitive).

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way.
lets assume you have basic_model.php inside your model folder .
Now add the code for `class Basic_Model` that you have written

```
class Basic_Model extends CI_MODEL {

  function __construct() {
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
  }

}
```

Now make a pagina_model.php  inside your model folder and add the code that you written. Just include the first line like bellow

```
<?php
  require APPPATH.'/models/basic_model.php';//just add this line and keep rest 
  class Pagina_Model extends Basic_Model {

      function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
      }
   }
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

You can do this ... MY_ model is really good but should you wish a sub model to extend a different sub model you can always do:

```
require(APPPATH.'models/Other_model.php');
class New_model extends Other_Model {
```

In my instance Other_Model actually extends MY_model.