# Load a model in Codeigniter 3.0.3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project whith this structure in controllers folder:

- places.php
- users.php
- items.php
- ...

And in my models folder:

1. Place.php (the name inside is class Place extends ActiveRecord\Model)
2. User.php
3. ...

Inside my controller places.php if I want to load a model I have to do just that:

```
$this->load->model('Place');
```

And after that I have to call my method like that:

```
$this->place->get_all_places();
```

It was work in my localhost but not in my server I check my php version in the server and it's 5.6.

How I can fix that?

That's my model file **Place.php**

```
    class Place extends ActiveRecord\Model
    {
        static $table_name = 'places';
        static $has_many = array(
        );


        public function get_all_places()
        { 
            return true;
        }
}
```

That's my controller file **places.php**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Places extends MY_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

            if($this->user){
                $access = TRUE;

            }else{
                redirect('login');
            }

        }   
        function index()
        {
            $this->content_view = 'places/all';
        }

        function get_places(){

            $this->theme_view = '';

            $this->load->model('Place');
            $this->place->get_all_places();
        }
}
```

And the error it was that:

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: place
```

Comment: try `$this->Place->get_all_places()`

Comment: I tried but doesnt work. It seems like dont load the model. The error message I get it's that:Unable to locate the model you have specified: place

Comment: Add more of your controller and model code, it's hard to find the problem that way.

Comment: Please read this http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: Try extending from "CI_Model" inside the "ActiveRecord\Model" class...You need to extend from CI_Model :T if you need to use another way to load models (custom models) then, create a library for it and not using the models system from CI

Comment: This may help also about extending model  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28001003/extends-model-in-codeigniter

Comment: The all system it works in this way and when I need to get some data i have to do something like Place::all (); for example it looks like something integrated with a datamapper orm but it's not. I cannot just extend from CI_Model because I need to work with Activerecord\Model.  It's a strange thing because remember on my local host it works great just only on the real server it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Your model file name should be

```
Places_model.php
```

and inside model

```
class Places_Model extends CI_Model # Changed 
{
    static $table_name = 'places';
    static $has_many = array();


    public function get_all_places()
    { 
        return true;
    }

}
```

[Models in Codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html)

Comment: But I have to change necessary the CI_Model? Because my entire project it works with this class Place extends ActiveRecord\Model =S

Answer (score 0):

I think every thing is right.But the problem is due to this line..

```
class Place extends ActiveRecord\Model
```

If you define a new model which extends the `CI_Model`.And then name of new model can not like as `ActiveRecord\Model`.Name may be as `ActiveRecordModel`.SO one solution for you can be..replace above line as below if you define the new model named as   `ActiveRecordModel` in `application/core` folder.

```
class Place extends ActiveRecordModel
```

Another solution can be if you have not define any new model.then just replace above line as

```
 class Place extends CI_Model
```

Comment: Hi @Hikmat Sijapat I try what you said but doesn't work. Always the same error Unable to locate the model you have specified: place, Place or Place_Model